# rails 4 : NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to migrate my rails application from rails 3 version to rails 4 version.I am using devise gem for authentication and using devise gem version '3.0.0' . whenever i try to login in my app i am getting below error

```
undefined method `is_flashing_format?' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x42422e8>
```

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: Looks similar to this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507963/overwriting-deviseregistrationscontroller-with-custom-create-gives-nomethode)

Comment: check this post! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507963/overwriting-deviseregistrationscontroller-with-custom-create-gives-nomethode

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my devise gem version to '3.4.1' and its working fine.

Thanks,