# Can't create new users: " NoMethodError in Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController#create " ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have utilized a repository from GIT to set up on my server. I went through the entire set up process. Did some troubleshooting.. now for some reason i cant create new user accounts. I get the error below. And before pointing me to other answer, please help me understand which files I have to edit.

Source for repository: https://github.com/cidadedemocratica/cidadedemocratica

I have read these answers:

- [Overwriting 'Devise::RegistrationsController' with custom create gives NoMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507963/overwriting-deviseregistrationscontroller-with-custom-create-gives-nomethode)
- [Get NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490699/get-nomethoderror-in-deviseregistrationscontrollercreate)

But I don't understand how to apply them or if they fix my issue because of course they address a different issue.

This is the error I get:

**NoMethodError in Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController#create**

```
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:141:in `<=>'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:359:in `compare_with_coercion'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `=='
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:419:in `_run__2499102060664963072__create__1924821350065893665__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__2499102060664963072__save__1924821350065893665__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
devise (3.5.10) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:469:in `_run__1574262533890227630__process_action__1539992924850539872__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:43:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
bullet (4.5.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:11:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.19) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4080662334186913161__call__1924821350065893665__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.19) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.19) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.2.2) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.2.2) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.19) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"EDITEDTOKENOUT=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"email@emailserver.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Cadastrar"}
```

Show session dump

Show env dump

```
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.2"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.5"
REMOTE_ADDR: "Hidden"
SERVER_NAME: "Hidden"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
```

Response

Headers:

None

On `Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController`

I have:

```
class Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :if => proc { |c| c.signed_in? && c.current_user.admin? }

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    waiting_for_confirmation_path(resource)
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController` look like?

Comment: From here: https://github.com/cidadedemocratica/cidadedemocratica/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/custom/registrations_controller.rb

this is what I see:

`class Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :if => proc { |c| c.signed_in? && c.current_user.admin? }

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    waiting_for_confirmation_path(resource)
  end
end`

Comment: Yeah, please add it to the question itself, it's better.

Comment: Added. I dont know which formatting to use to make my code look neat. I saw you edited the big block in my question. I spent nearly half an hour trying to find the setting to format my code but I could not find it. I use the code feature but other quotes are breaking the formatting.

Comment: You can either use the code formatting button or indent your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhh  thanks!

Comment: I guess, it has something to do with Time. Probably something with server's time setting.

Comment: That file is on the bottom of my question. Is there a way to bypass that comparison?